# Changing column in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to change part of the string in a column of a data frame. I, however, can not get it to update in the data frame. This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd

#File path
csv = '/home/test.csv'

#Read csv to pandas
df = pd.read_csv(nuclei_annotations_csv, header=None, names=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

#Select Data to update
paths = df['A']

#Loop over data
for x in paths:
    #Select data to updte
    old = x[:36]
    #Update value
    new = '/Datasets/RetinaNetData'
    #Replace
    new_path = x.replace(old, new)
    #Save values to DataFrame
    paths.update(new_path)

#Print updated DataFrame 
print(df)
```

The inputs and output I would like are:

Input:

```
/Annotations/test_folder/10_m03293_ORG.png
/Annotations/test_folder/10_m03293_ORG.png
/Annotations/test_folder/10_m03293_ORG.png
/Annotations/test_folder/10_m03293_ORG.png
```

OutPut:

```
/Datasets/RetinaNetData/10_m03293_ORG.png
/Datasets/RetinaNetData/10_m03293_ORG.png
/Datasets/RetinaNetData/10_m03293_ORG.png
/Datasets/RetinaNetData/10_m03293_ORG.png
```

Comment: So you are trying to replace the first 36 characters in each row of the `'A'` column with `'/Datasets/RetinaNetData'`?

Comment: can you show us an example of what the data is and what you want to acheive

Comment: @rahlf23 yes, basically change the directory held in the csv

Comment: See @ASGM's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all of the rows are strings and all of them have at least 36 characters, you can use [`.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) to get the part of the cells after the 36th character.  Then you can just use the `+` operator to combine the new beginning with the remainder of each cell's contents:

```
df.A = '/Datasets/RetinaNetData' + df.A.str[36:]
```

As a general tip, methods like this that operate across the whole dataframe at once are going to be more efficient than looping over each row individually.